# Show that the expected absolute deviation is quadratic near 0

Tags: probability, taylor-expansion

Let $X$ be a real valued random variable with median $0$ having a continuous, positive density (with respect to lebesgue measure) $f$ in a neighborhood of $0$. Show that:

$$g(t) = \mathbb E(|X - t| - |X|) = t^2f(0) + o(t^2)$$

as $t\rightarrow 0$.

I'm not sure how to show this since I would usually apply a taylor expansion for this kind of result, but my quantity of interest, $g$, appears to be non-differentiable with respect to $t$. If I could compute the expectation or approximate it somehow, then I might be able to show the result.

EDIT: for context, this is the first claim in section 2 of Pollard's `Asymptotics for least absolute deviation regression estimators`. See [link](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Epollard/Papers/Pollard91ET.pdf).

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but this looks off to me, take $X=1$ and $t\le 1$ then $E[|X-t|-|X|] = E [-t] = -t$ for any probability measure.

Comment: @copper.hat in that case $X$ does not have a positive density in a neighborhood of $0$

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate what that means? You mean there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $P[|X| < \epsilon] > 0$?

Comment: Specifically I mean that $X$ has a density with respect to lebesgue measure in a neighborhood of $0$, and that density is also strictly positive in a neighborhood around $0$. The example you gave has a distribution with an atom at $0$, so it does not have a density near $0$.

Comment: You might want to elaborate the question to clarify that the $f$ is the density of $X$.

Comment: I'm really sleepy so I wish I could answer this, but I'll make sure to do so once I wake up. +1.

Comment: I have no idea what $P[ |u_i -t| - |u_i| ] $ could mean in section 2 of the referenced document.

Comment: The notation they use is maybe different than what you're used to. $\mathbb P$ is the same as $\mathbb E$, the expectation operator. I think this is called di finetti notation.

Comment: This seems to be reasonably answered already, that's good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P_X$ be the measure induced by $X$. We are given that $P_X$ has a continuous, positive density $f$ in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Since $0$ is a (the) median of $X$, the conditions on $f$ allow us to conclude $P_X (-\infty,0] = P_X [0,\infty) = {1 \over 2}$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta>0$ such that $f$ is defined and positive on $[-\delta,\delta]$ and $|f(0)-f(\xi)| < \epsilon$ for $|\xi| < \delta$.

Choose $t \in [0,\delta)$, then
\begin{eqnarray}
E[|X-t|-X] &=& \int (|\xi-t| - |\xi|) P_X(d \xi) \\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^0 t P_X(d \xi) + \int_0^t (t-2 \xi) P_X(d \xi) - \int_t^\infty t P_X(d \xi) \\
&=&  \int_0^t (t-2 \xi) P_X(d \xi) + \int_0^t t P_X(d \xi) \\
&=& 2\int_0^t (t-\xi) f(\xi) m(d \xi) \\
&=& 2\int_0^t (t-\xi) f(0) m(d \xi) + 2\int_0^t (t-\xi) (f(\xi)-f(0)) m(d \xi)\\
&=& t^2 f(0) + 2\int_0^t (t-\xi) (f(\xi)-f(0)) m(d \xi)\\
\end{eqnarray}
The same analysis applies mutatis mutandis for $t \in (-\delta,0]$.

Under the above assumptions we see that
$|2\int_0^t (t-\xi) (f(\xi)-f(0)) m(d \xi)|  \le \epsilon t^2$.

Comment: Where does the very last claim come from?

Comment: $\int_0^t (t-\xi)  m(d \xi) = {t^2 \over 2}$. And $|f(\xi)-f(0)|$ is bounded by $\epsilon$.